# React-Dragula library on implementing drag and drop

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dragula

I am implementing [React-Dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/react-dragula) library for simple drag and drop in my project. I know each element should be div inside container according to there sample code but not getting any solution how to achieve this in my code.

This is the code-

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import dragula from 'react-dragula';

class NavBar extends Component {
componentDidMount () {
var container = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
console.log("dcdscscsccscd", container)
console.log("NavBar.........................................")
dragula([container]);
}
 render () {
  return(
  <div className="container">
    <nav className="navbar navbar-static-top">
      <div className="navbar-custom-menu">
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">

             <li> <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-     toggle="dropdown"> <i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>   Rate Search </a> </li>

              <li> <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i className="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Negotiation Worksheet </a> </li>
            </ul>
             <ul className="nav navbar-nav pull-right">

              <li> <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> </li>

              <li> <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i className="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span className="label label-warning">2</span> </a> </li>
              <li className="dropdown user user-menu dropdown" > <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i className="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
              <ul className="dropdown-menu user-info" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                <li className="user-header"> Jack Johnson </li>
                <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Preferences</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div> 
)}
}



 export default NavBar;
```

please let me know what I am doing wrong.
Thanks for any help in advance.